# Google Directory api in php without using composer

Tags: php, google-directory-api

I want to use Directory Api for adding members. Documentation provided by google says that to use composer. I don't want to use composer.

What is the best way to do this..

Comment: just read the doc... on the quickstart guide there is a link to alternative install options without using composer. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

Comment: @CassianCrozetLjdtm: Thanks for providing me document. but i am unable to find directory api for creating groups and adding memebers into group